# how to not use the default PHP 7.3 of Mac OSX Catalina 10.15.6 and use home brew php?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I was given a macbook 2019 for work which has catalina 10.15.6 ... the default PHP is 7.3 .. can someone show me the step by step on how to avoid this default PHP version?. I found some tutorials online using homebrew in order to use multiple versions of PHP. but then am a bit skeptical to install the homebrew php yet, coz I scare it will conflict with the default PHP with the OSX . any idea ?

Comment: Is the default php installed with mamp?

Comment: no it's not with mamp..it's in the OS itself..fresh out of the box

Comment: Check my answer below on how to do update

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Homebrew manages the installation for you and updates the necessary paths.

With homebrew installed you can just run the following command to install php7.4

```
brew update
brew install php@7.4
```

Check your PHP version now

```
php -v
```

If it still prints out the old version, update your path:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**Alternative one-line install**

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.4
```

Comment: i also installed apache using brew, what should I modify in the LoadModule ?

Comment: Add this:  `LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so` and comment out that of the older PHP version if you see it there

Comment: before following your instructions, I ran "which php", it says `/usr/bin/php` .... if I use homebrew php , will the export path overwrite that /usr/bin/php  ?

Comment: Yeah it should override

Comment: this one worked ...the export did the job..thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To do that, Within the terminal, Fire this command:

```
which php
```

This should output the path to the default PHP install which comes preinstalled by Mac OS X, by default it has to be
Now, We just need to swap this over to the PHP that is installed with MAMP, which is located at /Applications/Xampp/bin/php/php7.3/bin   for example

1. Within the Terminal, run vim ~/.bash_profile
2. Type i and then paste the following at the top of the file:

> `export PATH=/Applications/Xampp/bin/php/php7.3/bin:$PATH`

3. Hit ESC, Type ***:wq***, and hit Enter

> `In Terminal, run source ~/.bash_profile`

4. In Terminal, type in ***which php*** again and look for the updated string. If everything was successful, It should output the new path to MAMP PHP install.
5. In case it doesn't output the correct path, try closing the terminal window (exit fully) and open again, it should apply the changes (Restart in short).

[source : https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693](https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693)

Comment: i also installed apache using brew, what should I modify  in the LoadModule  ?